# How to find value of an attribute in a sub child node of an XML?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have a XML which has the following structure:

```
<Results>
<TestResultAggregation testName="MyOrder">
  <Counters error="0" failed="1" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0"/>
  <InnerResults>
    <UnitTestResult testName="TestMethod3" outcome="Failed">
      <Output>
        <ErrorInfo>
          <Message>Assert.Fail failed. </Message>
          <StackTrace>
            at Random.UnitTest1.TestMethod3()
          </StackTrace>
        </ErrorInfo>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
    <UnitTestResult testName="TestMethod2" outcome="Passed">
      <Output>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
  </InnerResults>
</TestResultAggregation>
```

When the result of 'outcome' attribute in 'UnitTestResult' is 'failed', I have to display the value of 'ErrorInfo' and 'StackTrace' nodes too. The catch here is that the **above schema is not fixed**. For eg,

```
<Results>
<UnitTestResult testName="TestMethod3" outcome="Failed">
      <Output>
        <ErrorInfo>
          <Message>Assert.Fail failed. </Message>
          <StackTrace>
            at Random.UnitTest1.TestMethod3()
          </StackTrace>
        </ErrorInfo>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
    <UnitTestResult testName="TestMethod2" outcome="Passed">
      <Output>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
```

The above schema can also be generated dynamically.

How to write a code for the above requirement in C#??

Answer (score 3):

Use LINQ2XML with [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx) method..

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
var result=doc.Descendants().Elements("UnitTestResult")
                   .Where(x=>x.Attribute("outcome").Value=="Failed")
                   .Select(x=>
                    new
                    {
                         Message=x.Element("Output")
                                  .Element("ErrorInfo")
                                  .Element("Message").Value,
                         StackTrace=x.Element("Output")
                                     .Element("ErrorInfo")
                                     .Element("StackTrace").Value
                    });
```

---

Now you can iterate over `result`

```
foreach(var error in result)
{
    error.Message;
    error.StackTrace;
}
```

Comment: Getting an error in the where clause .Where(x=>x.Attribute("outcome")=="Failed"), which says "Operator == can't be applied to operands..."

Comment: do `x.Attribute("outcome").Value`

Comment: it didn't work, I am afraid. Getting some cryptic data in 'result' variable and the foreach loop over result is exiting without any output. :(

Comment: @user2795006 it works perfectly for the above xml..i have tested it

Comment: The xml is just as i mentioned above. The thing here is, my file is in .trx format which I am loading as an XML. Then I am parsing this file as a string using string xmlStr = Doc.ToString();                       XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.ToString().Contains(@"<UnitTestResult testName=""TestMethod2"" outcome=""failed"">"))
{

}
```

This won't be a popular answer I know.

Comment: This requires you to already know the full xml element string you're looking for, or at best to know the values of the attributes you're searching for.